# How to set a routing table that prefers wlan dhcp interface as default route?

Tags: linux, debian, networking

`eth0` has a static IP set in `/etc/interfaces`

`wlan0` gets it IP dynamically

How can I change my routing table and where would I put the command to always make wlan0 the default route so internet access will work?  Right now I can ssh into the box using either eth0 or wlan0 but internet access gets routed through eth0 always which does not work.

Also, are auto and allow-hotplug contradictory options?

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.20.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.20.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.20.1
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To defined a preferred interface, use the metric directive in the interfaces. The higher the value, the lower the priority.

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.20.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.20.1
    metric 30
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    metric 10
```

Then restart the networking service with:

```
service networking restart
```

From [Debian Reference - Chapter 5. Network setup](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html)

> The ifmetric package enables us to manipulate metrics of routes a
>   posteriori even for DHCP.
>
> The following sets the eth0 interface to be preferred over the wlan0
>   interface.
>
> Install the ifmetric package.
>
> Add an option line with "metric 0" just below the "iface eth0 inet
>   dhcp" line in "/etc/network/interfaces".
>
> Add an option line with "metric 1" just below the "iface wlan0 inet
>   dhcp" line in "/etc/network/interfaces".
>
> The metric 0 means the highest priority route and is the default one.
>   The larger metric value means lower priority routes. The IP address of
>   the active interface with the lowest metric value becomes the
>   originating one. See ifmetric(8).

Comment: Sweet that works.  Thx.

Comment: Far better than messing up with routes in run time, and then redoing it in every reboot.