# How to make wlan to always be the default route? (ip route list)

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

Whenever I add my 4G modem to my raspberry, it gets on top of the default routes ou `ip route list`, however I want everything to go through wlan, and only use the 4G modem to receive SSH connections.

I've found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/836708) on how to disable the default routes.

however, after reboot, the 4G modem comes back to the top.

How do I make `wlan0` to always be the first rule on default?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the dmesg output when I connect the USB dongle:

```
[426102.910168] usb 1-1.5.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[426103.046670] usb 1-1.5.1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[426103.056674] usb 1-1.5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1f01
[426103.056693] usb 1-1.5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[426103.056704] usb 1-1.5.1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[426103.056714] usb 1-1.5.1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[426103.056724] usb 1-1.5.1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[426103.121355] usb-storage 1-1.5.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[426103.122875] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.5.1:1.0
[426103.987177] usb 1-1.5.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[426105.470211] usb 1-1.5.1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[426105.606666] usb 1-1.5.1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[426105.615673] usb 1-1.5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc
[426105.615692] usb 1-1.5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[426105.615703] usb 1-1.5.1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[426105.615713] usb 1-1.5.1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[426105.766297] usb-storage 1-1.5.1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[426105.766768] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.5.1:1.2
[426105.855053] cdc_ether 1-1.5.1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.5.1, CDC Ethernet Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[426105.855593] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[426106.785653] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[426106.803758] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[426106.820687] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Here's `ip addr`

```
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::584f:751f:bb3e:e26b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**UPDATE 2**

I attached it a few more times until it showed the `eth1` route:

```
[10787.229141] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[10787.363515] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0606
[10787.363533] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10787.363544] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB Hub 2.0
[10787.363555] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: ALCOR
[10787.365166] hub 1-1.5:1.0: USB hub found
[10787.369831] hub 1-1.5:1.0: 4 ports detected
[10797.419094] usb 1-1.5.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[10797.555636] usb 1-1.5.1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[10797.565759] usb 1-1.5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1f01
[10797.565777] usb 1-1.5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[10797.565789] usb 1-1.5.1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[10797.565799] usb 1-1.5.1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[10797.565808] usb 1-1.5.1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[10797.630477] usb-storage 1-1.5.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[10797.631101] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.5.1:1.0
[10798.472745] usb 1-1.5.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[10799.469081] usb 1-1.5.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
[10799.630768] usb 1-1.5.1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[10799.646891] usb 1-1.5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc
[10799.646909] usb 1-1.5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10799.646920] usb 1-1.5.1: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[10799.646930] usb 1-1.5.1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[10799.814489] usb-storage 1-1.5.1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[10799.815008] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.5.1:1.2
[10799.897788] cdc_ether 1-1.5.1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.5.1, CDC Ethernet Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
[10799.898127] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[10800.889652] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[10800.910585] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[10800.923297] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Here's `route -n`

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    207    0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     204    0        0 docker0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     206    0        0 veth4557ad2
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     207    0        0 eth1
```

See that I did `ifmetric wlan0` in order to be able to use the `wlan0` to `ssh` into my raspberry

**UPDATE 09/10:**

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    up ifmetric wlan0 0
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

This won't make my `wlan0` have metric 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First step is to find out *why* the 4G modem gets a default route. Does it do DHCP? If yes, figure out what calls it (network manager? traditional ifup/ifdown?), and configure dhclient etc. in that call to not set the default route for that particular interface.

Comment: @dirkt it's a USB dongle, so when it is connected it gets a new interface by default. There's no rule for eth1 on /etc/network/interfaces, however this is the ethernet device assigned to it. Do you know why? I don't know if it does DHCP, the interface is pretty simple, there's no advanced things to change or look. It's a huawei modem. Could you give soe help?

Comment: Please edit the question with the output of `dmesg` and syslog (use `journalctl` if you have systemd) after you plug in the USB dongle (indent 4 spaces for proper formatting on stackoverflow).

Comment: @dirkt I'll post the dmesg soon when I get somebody to plug the 4G modem for me. In the meantime, how do I find which thing is giving an IP address for my router? I'm using raspbian which is debian based so do you have an idea?

Comment: In general, you'll get IP addresses via [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), usually by calling `dhclient`, or, if the modem uses a point-to-point protocol, from this protocol. All that *should* be shown somewhere in the logs, which is why I was asking for the logs. If you don't have physical access to the RaspPi (you didn't mention this), `ip link` or `ip addr` should also show if it's a point-to-point protocol or not (possibly you need verbose mode).

Comment: @dirkt just edited with `dmesg` and `ip addr`  please take a  look

Comment: @dirkt strangely, this time `ip route list` didn't list it, that is, no `eth1` appears

Comment: Could you share you `/etc/network/interfaces` content?

Comment: Ok, `dmesg` says it's not point-to-point, so you'll get route via DHCP. What does syslog/journalctl say?

Comment: When you had wireless router and 4G USB modem separated hardware. You had set default route on wireless router permanently. the default route will not change again.You connected 4G USB modem to 4G provider. You got dynamic remote IP address and default route from 4G provider. You messed up between wireless and serial connection. When your 4G USB modem can not  do ppp over ethernet. How can you set default route?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292940/how-to-set-a-routing-table-that-prefers-wlan-dhcp-interface-as-default-route

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For changing the routing priority for an interface, you change metrics.

By default, all are 0, which is the highest priority. So, you can do:

```
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
    up ifmetric eth1 30
```

To use `ifmetric` in Debian, you have got to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ifmetric
```

> ifmetric
>
> Set routing metrics for a network interface
>
> ifmetric is a Linux tool for setting the metrics of all IPv4 routes
> attached to a given network interface at once. This may be used to
> change the priority of routing IPv4 traffic over the interface. Lower
> metrics correlate with higher priorities.
>
> The metric 0 means the highest priority route and is the default one.
> The larger metric value means lower priority routes. The IP address of
> the active interface with the lowest metric value becomes the
> originating one. See ifmetric(8).

Comment: Maybe you should also explain why this will help getting DHCP from a particular interface (instead of ignoring it) if there are other interfaces present.

Comment: @dirkt could you explain better the dhcp thing? I currently have iface wlan0 inet manual
    up ifmetric wlan0 0 but wlan0 metric won't appear as 0

Answer (score 1):

This is the good old problem of how to override a default route.

The easiest way for IPv4 is not to try and change the metric/priority but split the route:

```
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via wlan0-gw
ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via wlan0-gw
```

The reason this works is that routing table lookups are performed using a longest-matching-prefix search. Route metrics come into play only when there are two otherwise equivalent routes. In this case, these two routes have a 1-bit prefix which is longer than the 0-bits prefix of the default route (0.0.0.0/0) and will be consulted first. Since these two routes cover the whole of 0.0.0.0/0, they will always have preference over the default route.

An alternative approach is to use a separate routing table with the default route you prefer and add a rule to send all traffic there. I've never seen any automation that messes with ip rules, so it won't matter what other routes they add. The problem here is that your automation won't be able to insert additional routes though.

So, tl;dr:

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
    up ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via wlan0-gw
    up ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via wlan0-gw
    ....
```

Or (but you will also have to add all other routes to "table 5"):

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
    up ip rule add to 0.0.0.0/0 table 5
    up ip route add default via wlan0-gw table 5
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to Persist the `ip route add/del` in debian is to write them down into `/etc/network/interfaces` like below:

```
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
    post-up ip route del default
    post-up ip route add default via <gateway IP> dev wlan0
```

Comment: I think this way it will just add a default gateway for each interface, but not which one is used preferably

Comment: Ok I understood, it will exclude the default one and add one for wlan0. But won't a default one for eth0 be added too?

Answer (score 0):

I think the matter on default gateway. Here is the tutorial.

I briefly explain the steps. First, you need to delete the default gateway and add the one you want to add. Then, you edit "/etc/network/interfaces" for permanent change. Finally, you restart the service.

https://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Change-the-Default-Gateway-in-Linux